# Grails Web Application Saving file permission Denied

Tags: json, grails, web-applications, access-rights, access-rules

I am using the web application to write a file on server. It has working fine till we changed the directory.

we had directory /data/files/JSON previously
We changed it to /data/test/JSON and now we are not able to write files in the directory.

Following is the output from log file

Cannot store JSON file for test fvHvjVvYvd: /data/test/JSON/fvHvjVvYvd.json (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/test/JSON/fvHvjVvYvd.json (Permission denied)

Why it is happening

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your user had the rights to write on path /data/files/JSON and since you have changed the path verify if the user has rights to write in new directory.